# Make robocopy skip offline computers in text-file

Tags: batch, script, robocopy

I'm trying to write a batch file that will `robocopy` a msi file from a server to all the domain PCs that are online at that time.
It should skip PCs that already have the file listed and PCs that are offline.

Currently I'm using this.

```
for /f %%i in (\\domain.lan\folder\folder\computers.txt) do robocopy c:\software\msifolder \\%%i\c$\install /MIR
```

After that I'm using `psexec` to open a CMD on the target PC and run the MSI with `msiexec`

```
psexec \\computername.domain.lan -u domain\"Username" -p "Password" cmd >> \domain.lan\folder\folder\software.install.txt 2>&1
msiexec.exe /quiet  /i c:\install\software.msi /norestart
```

The idea is to let this script run as a task for a week to install a program on as many PCs as possible unattended.

The `psexec` and `msiexec` are working fine. But the `robocopy` keeps retrying to access PCs that are offline. It should just skip to the next computer.

I tried to include as much info as possible. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Try and ping em, if no response, don't do the robocopy

Answer (score 0):

Add the `/W` and `/R` switches to your RoboCopy command.

Per [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
/r:<N>    Specifies the number of retries on failed copies.
          The default value of N is 1,000,000 (one million retries).

/w:<N>    Specifies the wait time between retries, in seconds.
          The default value of N is 30 (wait time 30 seconds).
```

So the command:

```
robocopy c:\software\msifolder \\%%i\c$\install /MIR /R:1 /W:1
```

Would retry once after a one second interval, then abandon the copy if the remote machine is offline.

Comment: This was very helpful. Works like a charm.

Comment: Glad it worked. Be sure to upvote/accept the answer accordingly.